# zsh run script without sudo

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, oh-my-zsh

I made a bash script `helpme` that contains help configurations tasks that I use daily.

I would like to use it everywhere (even in other machines) with simple running:

```
$ helpme
```

I made this for that:(MAC OS)

```
$ sudo chmod +x helpme
$ sudo mv helpme /usr/local/bin/helpme
```

If I use `bash` terminal works correctly but now I'm using `oh-my-zsh` terminal and it shows me this message:

```
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -L | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid]
usage: sudo -l[l] [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-U username] [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid] file ...
```

If I run with `sudo` works, but I don't want to use `sudo`

```
$ sudo helpme
```

**Edited:**

This is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

main(){
 echo invalid option
}

if [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" = "${0}" ]]; then
    main "$@"
fi
```

Any idea?

Comment: What are the contents of the helpme script ?

Comment: @SamuelPeter I added an example. tks